# How we will send the different email template for reset password and confirm sign up in AWS cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I want to change the email template with both apis(signup, forgotPassword) of AWS Cognito. because I need to add a link to the code verify on that pages.

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And check out the [tour] page for a free badge!

Comment: You can use ses and lambda triggers to customize you email message.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go is using 3rd party providers for sending Emails in Cognito. This can be done with a custom lambda EmailCustomSender, but it can be only set by the console.

Comment: I have fixed this issue using creating a new lamda function on AWS Cognito and trigger that function on events.

Comment: Thats what I mean, the EmailCustomSender is a AWS Cognito event Lambda, but it only can be assign by the console. There is no way to do it from the web